# How can I get GoogleFinance to see 1 year and 5 year return of a stock?

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

You can use GOOGLEFINANCE("name", "return52") for mutual funds, but not for stocks. Is there another way to get the same result?

Answer (score 9):

If the cell is formatted as a NUMBER:

```
=ROUND( ( GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price") / index(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price", datevalue(today()-365) ) , 2,2) - 1 ) * 100 ,2)
```

Alternative:

```
=ROUND( ( GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price") / index(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price", date(year(today())-1,month(today()),day(today()))) , 2,2) - 1 ) * 100 ,2)
```

If the cell formatted as PERCENT:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price") / index(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price", datevalue(today()-365) ) , 2,2) - 1
```

Alternative:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price") / index(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price", date(year(today())-1,month(today()),day(today()))) , 2,2) - 1
```

Comment: I just found this answer, and it’s exactly what I was looking for! Thanks. That said, I’m a little confused as to how everything in the formula works. Specifically, can you tell me why the “2,2) - 1” at the end is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Added IFERROR this works better:

```
=IFERROR(ROUND((GOOGLEFINANCE(A2, "price")/index(GOOGLEFINANCE(A2,"open",datevalue(today()-365)), 2,2)- 1)*100,2))
```

Comment: Additionally, `=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",<expression>)`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is using the opening price at the beginning of the week.

```
=ROUND( ( GOOGLEFINANCE(A$4,"price") / index(GOOGLEFINANCE(A$4,"open", datevalue(today()-7) ) , 2,2) - 1 ) * 100 ,2)
```

Comment: Generally on StackExchange an upvote is all the thanks one needs. Answers are generally reserved for your unique answer to the original question. Side note: The down vote isn't mine; just explaining the likely reason someone clicked down.